# 16.04 LTS: bluetooth still running after turning it OFF, impossible to really stop bluetooth

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, dell, bluez

**The Problem:**

After bluetooth has been turned OFF via panel control, it still running, as the following command shows:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor    preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since lun. 2018-03-26 10:03:39 CEST; 22min ago
    Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 3713 (bluetoothd)
  Status: "Running"
  CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
          └─3713 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

Below, are additionnal information (tests of commands, configuration)

---

**Test of commands run:**

Regarding [the official ubuntu bluetooth documentation page](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/bluetooth/bluez/docs/reference/using-prerequisites) , here are  returns related to bluez:

```
snap interfaces bluez
Slot  Plug

snap interfaces | grep blue
:bluetooth-control         -
:bluez                     -

systemctl status snap.bluez.bluez.service
● snap.bluez.bluez.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

**Similar discussions**

A [similar discussion on ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326395) suggests solutions, but they do not solve my problem.

**Version and kernel:**

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS \n \l

uname -a
Linux dell-vostro1510 4.4.0-67-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 8 16:34:04 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**Computer type and brand**

DELL VOSTRO 1510

**Configuration:**

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000b]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63e0 Microdia Sonix Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Turning bluetooth off in the panel/bluetooth indicator doesn't stop the bluetooth service, but it powers the device off.</del>

You can check the power status using:

```
bluetoothctl <<< show | grep Powered
```

---

**Edit:**

My first assumption (device only gets powered off by the indicator switch) seems not to have been entirely correct. The "Powered: no" state seems to appear only occasionally, and is probably not the intended behaviour (bug?).

Usually, turning bluetooth off from the indicator or bluetooth settings soft-blocks the device using `rfkill`, which causes the device to entirely disappear from the `bluetoothctl` list (and coincidentally also makes the bluetooth indicator disappear, which can probably be considered another bug).

Please try turning it on and off again from the bluetooth indicator or settings...

You can check the `rfkill` blocking states of all wireless devices using

```
rfkill list
```

If bluetooth is turned off by software (not a hardware switch), you should expect something like this in the output:

```
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: bluetoothctl <<< show | grep Powered
          Powered: no

Comment: Return of the command "bluetoothctl <<< show | grep Powered" gives   "Powered: no". So, it seems power of bluetooth is OFF. However, it seems something has changed in computer behavior: before, the "bluetooth" light indicator of my DELL VOSTRO 1510 ladtop was OFF when bluetooth was turned OFF. And now, this light is still ON when "bluetooth" is turned OFF.

Comment: @user301828 I think my first version of the answer was wrong, please check it again now.

Comment: Here are the returns of `rfkill list`. When bluetooth is "ON", then its returns `Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no`, and when it is "OFF" its returns `Soft blocked: yes  Hard blocked: no`. What do you think ?

Comment: That sounds like correct behaviour to me.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Let say, that on Dell Vostro 1510, when the wifi and bluetooth card button in "ON" and when Ubuntu 16.04 LTS bluetooth management software is "OFF", then the blue hardware bluetooth light symbol keeps lighting, because the hardware part is still "ON", when the software is "OFF". The command `rfkill list` to enter in a prompt terminal, helps to verify this behaviour. To shutdown the bluetooth hardware, and shutdown the bluetooth light, the only way is to put the bluetooth hardware button on "OFF".